# Getting the text content of a linkbutton control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have linkbutton control in a gridview:

[image]

I am trying to get at text from these controls:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
}
```

This is the result:

```
Task











&nbsp;
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get to the Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindControl`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    LinkButton btn= ((LinkButton )e.Row.FindControl("YourControlId"));
    var text = btn.Text;
    //Here you have btn object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like below?

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btn");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the header row and only deal with data rows, like this:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore all other rows types (header, footer, etc.) except data rows
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
    }
}
```

For more information about the types of data rows in the grid view read [GridViewRow.RowType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3).